# How to select a child of child without firstChild or nth-child()?

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this:

```
<div id="unique_id">
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="common_class">
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to select the table in common_class, however, I am picking up other stuff.  I would like something like:

```
#unique_id > .common_class > table
```

However, that does not work.  For that to work div.common_class would have to be the child of div#unique_id.

Note: I must support IE7, so no nth-child() selector.  Also, I am trying to avoid javascript.  Note: firstChild is allowed, but I am looking for second div at one point.

GC

Comment: What about simply `#unique_id .common_class > table` ?

Comment: Take a look on this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp ... it might help you in the future, when it comes to CSS Selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#unique_id > .common_class` requires the `.common_class` to be a **direct** child of `#unique_id` (and this is not your case).

Just avoid the `>` there:

```css
#unique_id .common_class > table {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="unique_id">
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="common_class">
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or use the **exact** tree: `#unique_id > div > div > .common_class > table` (but you really **shouldn't** use this kind of css).

Comment: Please don't use `#unique_id > div > div > .common_class > table` lol

Comment: @JacobAlvarez I agree :) hehe. It's only an example for what the **exact** path would be. It shouldn't be used.